# Existing Joomla website - How to implement Mobile Theme + Functionality?

Tags: php, mobile, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I need to create a mobile website for a Joomla website that is already live and running (has been for a while). I have no experience in using Joomla, so hence why I am asking you Guru's on here! I need to be able to display news and their categories, and possibly a few sub pages of cut down text from the full site.

I have found a few Joomla Extensions which hint at redirecting users to a mobile theme.

See:

- [Mobile Joomla!](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/11722)
- [Architect for Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/9759)

Do these include a mobile theme with them? Or do you have to manually create a separate theme for these extensions to identify and use when a mobile device or tablet is visiting the website? If so - can any of you direct me to the best possible route of implementing a "simple" mobile theme based on the current website? And note any common pitfalls + issues.

[The website in question is here.](http://www.commodities-now.com/news.html)

I look forward to your answers - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that a mobile version (if optimized for mobile devices) looks quite different to a normal website, I would write my own code which accesses the joomla database. For example, you create an own subdomain (no need to check "show mobile version" on every page) and there you can create a very lean and fast php/html5 version, for example. The php accesses the joomla database and gets all the news you need. Writing your own code has some advantages (in imho):

- You can create a lean and dedicated version specific for your needs -> less code which handles generic things is needed
- You can use some sophisticated gui-tools like [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) to create a nice gui
- I don't think that there's a great community for mobile joomla websites...